# Synonyms for "never-ending issue"

Tags: synonyms, idiom-request

I would like to know some idiomatic expressions synonym to "never-ending issue" as in such a sentence:

> The deployment of IPv6 is one of the never-ending issues of the Internet

Comment: By *never-ending issue*, do you mean *a problem which is inherently insoluble* (so it ***will*** continue to be a problem forever), or the more figurative sense of *an issue which has long been, and **currently** continues to be, problematic* (but which ***might*** feasibly be resolved, perhaps soon)?

Comment: the more figurative sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "an ongoing issue" or an "endless issue" comes to mind.

Answer (score -1):

"*Persistent problem*" or "*persisting problem*" sound acceptable.

Also, grammatically, I'd use plural in "is one of the never-ending issue**s** ...".

Comment: Can you reference to where you have found those idioms? I couldn’t find them on the net. Thanks.

Comment: Really?  I just searched for "persistent problem", here is one link: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/persistent (see among examples).

Comment: A persistent problem is fine. It is not an idiom. It's just as adjective and a noun.

Answer (score -1):

There are many synonyms the OP can use in the sentence such as everlasting/eternal/,unceasing issue.

Comment: Please include an explanation of *why* each of these might be correct.

Comment: Nathan Tuggy, Correct me if I am wrong. I have often heard everlasting issue, everlasting/eternal/unceasing problem.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong. I think the answer (like basically all on ELL) needs an explanation to be useful.

Comment: No one would use these terms to express the idea in the OP's question in a business context.